Magento 2 : Product showing out of stock but In stock in admin
I have use Magento 2.4.6-p5 version. We have some products in our inventory that are in-stock in the backend but showing out-of-stock in frontend. If I make a product out-stock and then back to in-stock then it works fine(in-stock in frontend).let me know if someone has faced such issues.

Have you try by disabling the third party extensions which you use?

i have done that, still the same, make use on amasty and mirasvit

After disabling the third party extension, you need to run all magento commands.

yes i have done that, still same issue php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f

the issue is not with the extentions

Try to change theme one;s as well, for the cross verification.

Wondering if stock has to do with indexation ? Second question : when you say some products, did you notice a common thing between them (is it only a certain type) ?

it various from product to product. i did notice when a product has been out of stock for a while then the issues happens. reindexing does nothing

hi there, anyone with solutions for this

Anyone looking for a fix.
vendor/magento/module-inventory-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/StockStatusExpressionForDefaultStock.php
Line 49, $connection->getCheckSql('css.stock_status IS NOT NULL', 'css.stock_status', $stockItemInStockField) change to $connection->getCheckSql('css.stock_status IS NOT NULL', 'cisi.is_in_stock', $stockItemInStockField)
